# Difference between ORDER BY (VARCHAR) and ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(VARCHAR)

Tags: oracle, plsql

In the following set of two queries will it work as same of same set of values where in one case float and another case compare string of float with fixed size of values

```
SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE WHERE MAIN_ID = 'SomeVal' ORDER BY OBJ_ID ASC
```

In the above SQL, MAIN_ID used to filter associated rows and **OBJ_ID** is primary key of the **SAMPLE_TABLE**, Where OBJ_ID is a string of float numbers with fixed size in format 999999.9999, but when I tried **TO_NUMBER(OBJ_ID)** instead of **OBJ_ID** it shows unable to do conversion. So I kept as above and run and get results sorts as how it sorted when float is used.

My question are,

1. Will ORDER BY OBJ_ID and ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(OBJ_ID) will results in
   different order of results?
2. If so, are there any other solution rather than **TO_NUMBER** which
   can cater the String which is correct format like 999999.9999 and
   which are not at with same query ?

   For an example the row OBJ_ID has following values
   181001.2122, 181001.2123, 181001.2143, abcd, abc.efg
   where last two values are accidental values which represents a rejected 
   entry, are there any ways to write a single sql which will correctly order the first three floats which are actually string with format **"999999.9999"**

Comment: This isn't a sql question, it applies to all languages. Strings are compared character by character as if organising a dictionary. The character `0` comes before `8`, which means that the string `09` comes before `8`. Just like `az` comes before `x`. Just because YOU ascribe a decimal meaning to the string doesn't mean anything.

Comment: thats fine, are there any solution for the 2nd question mentioned.

Comment: That there is even a second question isn't clear.  Please make it clearer. Preferably citing examples.

Comment: I have edited check please

Comment: Have you tried to order by `TO_NUMBER(OBJ_ID, 'FM999999.9999')`? The problem that the values cannot be transformed to a number could be caused by the NLS-Settings, so with explicitly specifying the format this could work better...

Comment: I have tried TO_NUMBER(OBJ_ID, '999999.9999') not this one

Comment: this works fine

Comment: Yes without the `FM` in the format mask - numbers like 123.45 do not work, as oracle expects some spaces to fit the format mask, with the `FM` oracle doesn't care about those. So I do ever work with `FM` as it gives allmost allways better results (in both directions)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sorting(comparison) of strings/varchar is different from the sorting(comparison) of numbers.

In numbers `2<11`, in strings/varchar `"2">"11"`

Assuming you sort ASC, if you dont convert to numbers, you have the row with "2" after the row with id= "11", and vice versa if you convert to numbers

Comment: yes I Know that, will there be any different if fixed length string used.

Answer (score 1):

String sorting is more complicated, and database can use various approach for this.
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch5lingsort.htm

```
with src as (
select '1' x from dual
union 
select '2' from dual
union
select '10' from dual)
select x from src order by x;


with src as (
select '1' x from dual
union 
select '2' from dual
union
select '10' from dual)
select x from src order by to_number(x);
```

Solution with lpad

```
with src as (
select '1' x from dual
union 
select '2' from dual
union
select '10' from dual)
select x from src order by lpad(x,10,'0');
```

Answer (score 0):

As Kristjan Kica answered, with varchar you sort with varchar you get alphabetic order. And if you sort by number you get numeric order.

Comment: Are there any choice for 2nd questions